# Workflow formula - If Email field is populated with either 2 people then workflow email alert is sent

Tags: workflow, email-alert

If Email field is populated with either 2 people (Sam or Mark) then workflow email alert is sent. Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'or()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

IF
(OR(RIO__r.Email = "email address" || "email address"))

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us a ton of information, but I think the main issue here is that you're missusing the double-pipe (another way to perfom a boolean "or") operator.

In general, your formula syntax is pretty wrong (using IF() without specifying 3 parameters, the IF() is probably unnecessary, using 2 separate OR operators with both usages being incorrect).

I'd recommend spending some time reading the [documentation on formula functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5) to avoid simple syntax errors like what you have here.

On to the main problem...
You can't use `||` like that to compare one thing to two (or more) values.
You need to be more explicit, and compare your email field to each value individually.

Wrong way:

`MyObj__c.Email = 'email1' || 'email2'`

Right way:

```
OR(
    MyObj__c.Email = 'email1',
    MyObj__c.Email = 'email2'
)
```